# How to wait for 2 values to resolve before sending them together to child component in angular 2?

Tags: angular, observable

I am having problem with code below, I am new to Angular 2, my child component tries to make getTacs but parameters are null as my parent component is still processing obervables...

How to make sure child component only initial when I have both currentUser and selectedUser in the parent component ?

Parent component has this,

```
    <ng-container>
      <div [@toggleAnimation]="showProduct" *ngIf="showProduct">
        <ppp-cobo-product
          [directoryReference]="currentUser" 
          [locationReference]="selectedUser">
        </ppp-cobo-product>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
```

and

```
currentUser: string;
selectedUser: string;

currentUserSubscription: string;
selectedUserSubscription: string;

ngOnInit() {
    this.getSelectedUser();
    this.getCurrentUser();
}


public getCurrentUser(): void {
    this.currentUserSubscription = this.myService.getCurrentUser().subscribe((data: myDto) => {
      this.currentUser = data.currentUser;
    });
}

public getSelectedUser(): void {
    this.selectedUserSubscription = this.myService.getSelectedUser().subscribe((data: myDto) => {
      this.selectedUser = data.selectedUser;
    });
}
```

Then child component is like this,

```
@Input() User1: string;
@Input() User2: string;

userTac$: Observable<UserTacDto[]>;
userTac: UserTacDto[];

ngOnInit() {
   this.getSomeOtherData();
}

  getSomeOtherData(): void {
    this.userTac$ = this.userTacService.getTacs(this.User1, this.User2)
      .map((tacs: UserTacDto[]) => {

        this.userTacService.doTacs(tacs, this.User1, this.User2)
          .subscribe((moreTacs: MoreUserTacDto[]) => {
            // some other logic
        });

        return this.userTac;
      })
      .catch((error: Response) => {
        this.error = error;
        return  Observable.throw(error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: I would first suggest `forkJoin` (though not related to issue): https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html then either use a [setter](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter) for the @Input, or [ngOnChanges](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-ngonchanges) to track when values are available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **combineLatest** or **forkJoin** several Observables and then on subscription you can do whatever you want -in this case redirect :

```
combineLatest([
      observable1$,
      observable2$,
    ])
     .subscribe(([result1, result2]) => {
       /// Redirect or whatever you want
      });
```

Or

```
forkJoin(
      observable1$,
      observable2$,
     )
     .subscribe(([result1, result2]) => {
       /// Redirect or whatever you want
      });
```

Defferences:

> forkJoin emits when all observables are completed

And

> combineLatest emits whenever any observable emits a value

I recommend you read the differences between combineLatest and forkJoin by the following urls to find the one suits you:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this with forkJoin. Tried to simulate your code as much as I could.

```
ngOnInit() {
       forkJoin(
         this.getSelectedUser(),
         this.getCurrentUser()
    )
    .subscribe(([res1, res2]) => {
        this.currentUser = res1.currentUser;
        this.selectedUser = res2.selectedUser;
    });
}


public getCurrentUser() {
    return this.myService.getCurrentUser();
}

public getSelectedUser() {
    return this.myService.getSelectedUser();
}
```

You can if course use directly the service getters instead of hiding then in a function.

FYI. If you get here from a route, you can use resolvers to make sure that you have all the data needed for such a case. Check resolvers [here](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)

Answer (score 0):

Why just not use the **@Input** with set declaration.

```
protected _user1: string;
protected _user2: string;

@Input()
set User1(value: string) {
    this._user1 = value;
    this.getSomeOtherData();
}

get User1(): string {
    return this._user1;
}

@Input()
set User2(value: string) {
    this._user2 = value;
    this.getSomeOtherData();
}

get User2(): string {
    return this._user2;
}
```

And in your method check for the users

```
  getSomeOtherData(): void {
    if(this._user1 != undefined && this._user2 != undefined){
    this.userTac$ = this.userTacService.getTacs(this.User1, this.User2)
      .map((tacs: UserTacDto[]) => {

        this.userTacService.doTacs(tacs, this.User1, this.User2)
          .subscribe((moreTacs: MoreUserTacDto[]) => {
            // some other logic
        });

        return this.userTac;
      })
      .catch((error: Response) => {
        this.error = error;
        return  Observable.throw(error);
      });
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [forkJoin](https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/performing-multiple-http-requests-in-angular-4-5-with-forkjoin-74f3ac166d61) in the Parent component like this:

**Parent Component TS**

```
currentUser: string;
selectedUser: string;
observableEvent$: Observable<any>;
currentUserSubscription: string;
selectedUserSubscription: string;

ngOnInit() {
    this.initialRequest();
}

public initialRequest(): void {
   this.observableEvent$ = forkJoin(this.myService.getCurrentUser(), this.myService.getSelectedUser()).pipe(tap(([res1, res2]) => {
     this.currentUser = res1.currentUser;
     this.selectedUser = res2.selectedUser;
   })
  );
}
```

Then in the html

```
<ng-container>
  <div [@toggleAnimation]="showProduct" *ngIf="showProduct && observableEvent$ | async">
    <ppp-cobo-product
      [directoryReference]="currentUser" 
      [locationReference]="selectedUser">
    </ppp-cobo-product>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

ppp-cobo-product-parent.html

```
<ng-container>
  <div [@toggleAnimation]="showProduct" *ngIf="showProduct">
    <ppp-cobo-product
      [directoryReference]="currentUser$ | async" 
      [locationReference]="selectedUser | async">
    </ppp-cobo-product>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

ppp-cobo-product-parent.ts

```
currentUser$: Observable<string>;
selectedUser$: Observable<string>;    

constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.currentUser$ = this.myService.getCurrentUser().pipe(map(user => user.currentUser));
   this.selectedUser$ = this.myService.getSelectedUser().pipe(map(user => user.selectedUser));
}
```

ppp-cobo-product.ts

```
 @Input() directoryReference: string;
  @Input() locationReference: string;

  userTac$: Observable<UserTacDto[]>;
  userTac: UserTacDto[];

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.locationReference && this.directoryReference) {
      this.getSomeOtherData();
    }
  }

  getSomeOtherData(): void {
    this.userTac$ = this.userTacService.getTacs(
      this.directoryReference,
      this.locationReference
    ).pipe(
      exhaustMap((tacs: UserTacDto[]) =>
        this.userTacService.doTacs(tacs, this.directoryReference, this.locationReference)
          .pipe(
            tap(_ => {
              // some other logic
            })
          )),
      catchError((error: Response) => {
        this.error = error;
        return Observable.throw(error);
      }));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the child class:

```
class ChildClass implements OnChanges{
      @Input() User1: string;
      @Input() User2: string

        // Add this lifecycle method
       ngOnChanges(){
       this.User1 =  !!this.User1 ? this.User1 : '';
       this.User2=  !!this.User2 ? this.User2: '';
       //Call the function after this 
       this.getSomeOtherData();
    }

 }
```